# MySQLi query error

Tags: php, sql

Am I doing something wrong here?

Of course I am, hah otherwise it'd be working. Can anybody tell me what in these statements aren't allowed?

```
    $signedin = $_SESSION['signed_in'];
    mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE users SET last_created_article = NOW() WHERE username ="' . $signedin .'"');
```

Comment: What's the problem here?  How is it "not working"?  Have you checked `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: use mysqli_error() to find the error as $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ( false===$result ) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); here $query is your query
}
else {
  echo 'done.';
}

Comment: what si the error you are getting

Comment: @Yasin `now()` is a built-in mysql function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: from your query nothing seem wrong. any error you are getting paste it here

Comment: you could use date function in php,try that it may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use double quotes to wrap your mysql query, then you don't have to outquote the `$signedin`.

```
$signedin = $_SESSION['signed_in'];
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET `last_created_article` = NOW() WHERE `username` = '$signedin'");
```

Also, why isn't your mysql stuff in a class? You can find tons of them on the web. So all your connection related files are in one place. So you can simply do $db->query("");
Also, most of those mysql classes have very good debugging methods. I would send you mine, but it takes time to upload it to GitHub.

https://github.com/a1phanumeric/PHP-MySQL-Class/blob/master/class.MySQL.php

Here is something similar.

---

**EDIT:** So where is my mysql macro. In the readme, you can figure out how to use it. And this one will output an error right away, if something is wrong :)

### **http://kallevaravas.github.io/kvMysqlMacros/**

Comment: How does this answer the question?  What's wrong with the original code?

Comment: Well, let him first try to debug with this code, then we know what was wrong. Since mysql is very critical with the quotes and etc. So making the format correct, should fix the outcome. If it doesnt, he at least saw, how is the correct way to format mysql queries.

Comment: What's wrong with the original code?  That query was also formatted correctly.

Comment: Obviouslly the problem is somewhere else, but without anyone risking to answer, he wont ever get it fixed. My answer at least gives the direction to the golden path. Meaing, he needs to get better mysql method and then easily see the debug messages.

Comment: After some testing it turns out the variable wasn't set correctly. I used mysqli_error() and it returned nothing. So I was able to figure it out from there. Also learned a lot of new ways to format it, Thanks guys!

Comment: @Newbie I made my own personal mysql macro available for your. Rocket, simply wants points and cares about strict rules in this community, while I take his downvotes, but try to help the user to his higher goal.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas: Please stop arguing with me.  I didn't downvote you.  I was just trying to point out that `"'$signedin'"` and `'"' . $signedin .'"'` were exactly the same.  That's all I was doing.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you. Since I never said that there is a problem. I just started a debugging post. From there, it was clear, that he needs a better method for detecting sql errors. And from there we went to mysql macros. So all in all, his problem got solved. And he learned something new. And that's all that matters. But thanks anyways, for removing your downvote :)